# Dynamic position of custom model in Autodesk Forge

Tags: javascript, three.js, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I want to build a viewer forge that is connected to BIM 360. There is an additional feature in the form of a new object from THREE.js that can follow GPS Location (dynamic positioning of an model). so I mapped it into the FORGE viewer. As far as I know there are 3 ways to display a custom model on FORGE :

1. viewer.impl.scene.add(model)
2. viewer.overlays.addMesh(model)
3. modelBuilder.addMesh(model)

which one should I use for this case?

I also have a question, how to group the mesh with the sceneBuilder because after I tried it it didn't work, but when I used overlays it worked.

```
  this.viewer.loadExtension("Autodesk.Viewing.SceneBuilder").then(() => {
  this.sceneBuilder = this.viewer.getExtension(
    "Autodesk.Viewing.SceneBuilder"
  );
  this.sceneBuilder.addNewModel({}).then((modelBuilder) => {
    this.modelBuilder = modelBuilder;
    window.modelBuilder = modelBuilder;

    const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().fromGeometry(
      new THREE.SphereGeometry(5, 8, 8)
    );
    const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0000 });

    const head = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    mesh.matrix = new THREE.Matrix4().compose(
      new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 5),
      new THREE.Quaternion(0, 0, 0, 1),
      new THREE.Vector3(1, 1, 2)
    );
    const body = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    body.matrix = new THREE.Matrix4().compose(
      new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0),
      new THREE.Quaternion(0, 0, 0, 1),
      new THREE.Vector3(1, 1, 2)
    );

    const human = new THREE.Group();
    human.add(head);
    human.add(body);

    human.dbId = 100; // Set the database id for the mesh
    modelBuilder.addMesh(human);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, option 3 (using `SceneBuilder`) is recommended when you want the custom three.js object to **behave like other Forge models**, that is, to make it hoverable, selectable, etc. And option 2 (using `viewer.overlays`) can be used for all the other cases. I'm guessing in your case you don't need the human model to be selectable or have a dbID, so using `viewer.overlays.addMesh` is perfectly fine.

Also, I think the `ModelBuilder.addMesh` method only supports a "leaf" object, not a group, so if you do need to use groups, `viewer.overlays` is the way to go.

Comment: Thank you for answer, is it possilbe to load eg. human.fbx from client side ?

Comment: That depends on whether three.js (version 71 that's used by Forge Viewer) can load this file format. It might: https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_fbx.html

Comment: Is there any documentation where I can upload the 3D model locally?, so instead of creating a new custom model, it's better to load the human model from a file and interact with it. But I will still load the design BIM of the derivative model as the main benchmark

Comment: There are applications like https://sandbox.babylonjs.com or https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com that allow you to drag&drop a file into the webpage and load any 3D meshes in it. You could try something like that as well.

Comment: This is the source code of the glTF viewer: https://github.com/donmccurdy/three-gltf-viewer.

Comment: Is it possible to load SVF model from our server to Forge Viewer?  then does this external model have to be SVF format ?

Comment: Yes, you can load files to the viewer from different locations. The only requirement (explained in Terms of Service at the top of the viewer JavaScript file) is that the viewer assets (JS, CSS, images, etc.) must still be served from the Autodesk domain.

Comment: The viewer is mainly designed to load SVF files generated by the Model Derivative service, but it also supports native loading of couple more formats such as PDF, DWG, or glTF.